Magento 2 - Add 2 New fields in bundle item option Selection
I'm trying to create a module which adds 2 fields in bundle option.
I've already managed to add 2 field:

However, it doesn't save the values in my database.
The columns are created, but they are not populated with the correct values.
Here is my code:
Plugin\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Composite.php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Es100\ManageBundleMaxMin\Plugin\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;

use Magento\Bundle\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Composite as BundleComposite;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface;
use Magento\Bundle\Model\Product\Type;
use Magento\Bundle\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\BundlePanel;
use Magento\Bundle\Model\Selection;

class Composite
{
protected $locator;
protected $selection;

/**
 * @param LocatorInterface $locator
 * @param Selection $selection
 */
public function __construct(
    LocatorInterface $locator,
    Selection $selection
) {
    $this->locator = $locator;
    $this->selection = $selection;
}

public function afterModifyData(BundleComposite $subject, array $data)
{
    $product = $this->locator->getProduct();
    $modelId = $product->getId();
    $isBundleProduct = $product->getTypeId() === Type::TYPE_CODE;
    if ($isBundleProduct && $modelId) {
        foreach ($data[$modelId][BundlePanel::CODE_BUNDLE_OPTIONS][BundlePanel::CODE_BUNDLE_OPTIONS] as &$option) {
            foreach ($option['bundle_selections'] as &$selection) {
                $this->selection->load($selection['selection_id']);
                $selection['min_qty'] = $this->selection->getMinQty();
                $selection['max_qty'] = $this->selection->getMaxQty();
            }
        }
    }

    return $data;
}
}

Model\LinkManagement.php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Es100\ManageBundleMaxMin\Model;

use Magento\Bundle\Api\Data\LinkInterface;
use Magento\Bundle\Api\Data\LinkInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Bundle\Model\ResourceModel\Bundle;
use Magento\Bundle\Model\ResourceModel\BundleFactory;
use Magento\Bundle\Model\ResourceModel\Option\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Bundle\Model\Selection;
use Magento\Bundle\Model\SelectionFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper;
use Magento\Framework\EntityManager\MetadataPool;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class LinkManagement extends \Magento\Bundle\Model\LinkManagement
{
/**
 * @var StoreManagerInterface
 */
private $storeManager;

/**
 * @var MetadataPool
 */
private $metadataPool;

public function __construct(
    ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
    LinkInterfaceFactory $linkFactory,
    SelectionFactory $bundleSelection,
    BundleFactory $bundleFactory,
    CollectionFactory $optionCollection,
    StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper,
    MetadataPool $metadataPool
) {
    parent::__construct(
        $productRepository,
        $linkFactory,
        $bundleSelection,
        $bundleFactory,
        $optionCollection,
        $storeManager,
        $dataObjectHelper,
        $metadataPool
    );
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->metadataPool = $metadataPool;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 *
 * Mappa i campi min_qty e max_qty durante il salvataggio.
 */
protected function mapProductLinkToSelectionModel(
    Selection $selectionModel,
    LinkInterface $productLink,
    $linkedProductId,
    $parentProductId
): Selection {
    $selectionModel = parent::mapProductLinkToSelectionModel($selectionModel, $productLink, $linkedProductId, $parentProductId);

        $selectionModel->setData('min_qty', $productLink->getMinQty());
        $selectionModel->setData('max_qty', $productLink->getMaxQty());

    return $selectionModel;
  }
}

Plugin\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\BundleCustomOptions.php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Es100\ManageBundleMaxMin\Plugin\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;

 use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field;
 use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Input;
 use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\DataType\Number;
 use Magento\Bundle\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\BundleCustomOptions as MagentoBundleCustomOptions;

class BundleCustomOptions
{
const FIELD_MIN_QTY = 'min_qty';
const FIELD_MAX_QTY = 'max_qty';

public function afterModifyMeta(MagentoBundleCustomOptions $subject, array $meta)
{
    if (isset($meta['bundle-items']['children']['bundle_options']['children']['record']['children']['product_bundle_container']['children']['bundle_selections']['children']['record']['children'])) {
        $meta['bundle-items']['children']['bundle_options']['children']['record']['children']['product_bundle_container']['children']['bundle_selections']['children']['record']['children'][static::FIELD_MIN_QTY] = $this->getMinQtyFieldConfig(125);
        $meta['bundle-items']['children']['bundle_options']['children']['record']['children']['product_bundle_container']['children']['bundle_selections']['children']['record']['children'][static::FIELD_MAX_QTY] = $this->getMaxQtyFieldConfig(126);

        // Reorder table headings
        $actionDelete = $meta['bundle-items']['children']['bundle_options']['children']['record']['children']['product_bundle_container']['children']['bundle_selections']['children']['record']['children']['action_delete'];
        unset($meta['bundle-items']['children']['bundle_options']['children']['record']['children']['product_bundle_container']['children']['bundle_selections']['children']['record']['children']['action_delete']);
        $meta['bundle-items']['children']['bundle_options']['children']['record']['children']['product_bundle_container']['children']['bundle_selections']['children']['record']['children']['action_delete'] = $actionDelete;
    }

    return $meta;
}

protected function getMinQtyFieldConfig($sortOrder)
{
    return [
        'arguments' => [
            'data' => [
                'config' => [
                    'label' => __('Quantità Minima'),
                    'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                    'formElement' => Input::NAME,
                    'dataScope' => static::FIELD_MIN_QTY,
                    'dataType' => Number::NAME,
                    'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                    'validation' => [
                        'validate-number' => true,
                        'validate-zero-or-greater' => true
                    ],
                    'default' => 1,
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}

protected function getMaxQtyFieldConfig($sortOrder)
{
    return [
        'arguments' => [
            'data' => [
                'config' => [
                    'label' => __('Quantità Massima'),
                    'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                    'formElement' => Input::NAME,
                    'dataScope' => static::FIELD_MAX_QTY,
                    'dataType' => Number::NAME,
                    'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                    'validation' => [
                        'validate-number' => true,
                        'validate-zero-or-greater' => true
                    ],
                    'default' => 1,
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];
  }
}

Setup\UpgradeSchema.php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Es100\ManageBundleMaxMin\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $setup->startSetup();

    if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.0', '<')) {
        $connection = $setup->getConnection();
        $tableName = $setup->getTable('catalog_product_bundle_selection');

        if ($connection->isTableExists($tableName)) {
            if (!$connection->tableColumnExists($tableName, 'min_qty')) {
                $connection->addColumn(
                    $tableName,
                    'min_qty',
                    [
                        'type' => Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                        'nullable' => true,
                        'comment' => 'Quantità minima'
                    ]
                );
            }

            if (!$connection->tableColumnExists($tableName, 'max_qty')) {
                $connection->addColumn(
                    $tableName,
                    'max_qty',
                    [
                        'type' => Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                        'nullable' => true,
                        'comment' => 'Quantità massima'
                    ]
                );
            }
        }
    }

    $setup->endSetup();
 }
}


This is the whole code which works perfectly !!!!
you need to setMinQty and setMaxQty in this function below

di.xml
<type name="Magento\Bundle\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\BundleCustomOptions">
            <plugin name="aam_image_bundleCustomOptions" type="Aam\Image\Plugin\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\BundleCustomOptions" sortOrder="1"/>

</type> 
<type name="Magento\Bundle\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Composite">
            <plugin name="aam_image_composite" type="Aam\Image\Plugin\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Composite" sortOrder="1"/>

</type> 
    <preference for="Magento\Bundle\Model\LinkManagement" type="Aam\Image\Model\LinkManagement" />


LinkManagement.php

namespace Aam\Image\Model;
    use Magento\Bundle\Api\Data\LinkInterface;
    use Magento\Bundle\Api\Data\LinkInterfaceFactory;
    use Magento\Bundle\Model\ResourceModel\Bundle;
    use Magento\Bundle\Model\ResourceModel\BundleFactory;
    use Magento\Bundle\Model\ResourceModel\Option\CollectionFactory;
    use Magento\Bundle\Model\Selection;
    use Magento\Bundle\Model\SelectionFactory;
    use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface;
    use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper;
    use Magento\Framework\EntityManager\MetadataPool;
    use Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException;
    use Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException;
    use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
    use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
    
    class LinkManagement extends \Magento\Bundle\Model\LinkManagement
    {
    /**
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    private $storeManager;
    
    /**
     * @var MetadataPool
     */
    private $metadataPool;
    
    public function __construct(
    ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
    LinkInterfaceFactory $linkFactory,
    SelectionFactory $bundleSelection,
    BundleFactory $bundleFactory,
    CollectionFactory $optionCollection,
    StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper,
    MetadataPool $metadataPool
    ) {
    parent::__construct(
        $productRepository,
        $linkFactory,
        $bundleSelection,
        $bundleFactory,
        $optionCollection,
        $storeManager,
        $dataObjectHelper,
        $metadataPool
    );
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->metadataPool = $metadataPool;
    }
    
    
    
    public function saveChild(
    $sku,
    LinkInterface $linkedProduct
    ) {
    $product = $this->productRepository->get($sku, true);
    if ($product->getTypeId() != 'bundle') {
        throw new InputException(
            __('The product with the "%1" SKU isn\'t a bundle product.', [$product->getSku()])
        );
    }
    
    /** @var Product $linkProductModel */
    $linkProductModel = $this->productRepository->get($linkedProduct->getSku());
    if ($linkProductModel->isComposite()) {
        throw new InputException(__('The bundle product can\'t contain another composite product.'));
    }
    
    if (!$linkedProduct->getId()) {
        throw new InputException(__('The product link needs an ID field entered. Enter and try again.'));
    }
    
    /** @var Selection $selectionModel */
    $selectionModel = $this->bundleSelection->create();
    $selectionModel->load($linkedProduct->getId());
    if (!$selectionModel->getId()) {
        throw new InputException(
            __(
                'The product link with the "%1" ID field wasn\'t found. Verify the ID and try again.',
                [$linkedProduct->getId()]
            )
        );
    }
    $selectionModel = $this->mapProductLinkToBundleSelectionModel(
        $selectionModel,
        $linkedProduct,
        $product,
        (int)$linkProductModel->getId()
    );
    $selectionModel->setMinQty(1);
    $selectionModel->setMaxQty(43);
    try {
        $selectionModel->save();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        throw new CouldNotSaveException(__('Could not save child: "%1"', $e->getMessage()), $e);
    }
    
    return true;
    }
/**
     * Fill selection model with product link data.
     *
     * @param Selection $selectionModel
     * @param LinkInterface $productLink
     * @param ProductInterface $parentProduct
     * @param int $linkedProductId
     * @param string $linkField
     * @return Selection
     * @throws NoSuchEntityException
     */
    private function mapProductLinkToBundleSelectionModel(
        Selection $selectionModel,
        LinkInterface $productLink,
        ProductInterface $parentProduct,
        int $linkedProductId
    ): Selection {
        $linkField = $this->metadataPool->getMetadata(ProductInterface::class)->getLinkField();
        $selectionModel->setProductId($linkedProductId);
        $selectionModel->setParentProductId($parentProduct->getData($linkField));
        if ($productLink->getSelectionId() !== null) {
            $selectionModel->setSelectionId($productLink->getSelectionId());
        }
        if ($productLink->getOptionId() !== null) {
            $selectionModel->setOptionId($productLink->getOptionId());
        }
        if ($productLink->getPosition() !== null) {
            $selectionModel->setPosition($productLink->getPosition());
        }
        if ($productLink->getQty() !== null) {
            $selectionModel->setSelectionQty($productLink->getQty());
        }
        if ($productLink->getPriceType() !== null) {
            $selectionModel->setSelectionPriceType($productLink->getPriceType());
        }
        if ($productLink->getPrice() !== null) {
            $selectionModel->setSelectionPriceValue($productLink->getPrice());
        }
        if ($productLink->getCanChangeQuantity() !== null) {
            $selectionModel->setSelectionCanChangeQty($productLink->getCanChangeQuantity());
        }
        if ($productLink->getIsDefault() !== null) {
            $selectionModel->setIsDefault($productLink->getIsDefault());
        }
        $selectionModel->setWebsiteId((int)$this->storeManager->getStore($parentProduct->getStoreId())->getWebsiteId());

        return $selectionModel;
    }
    }

3.BundleCustomOptions (same as yours)
4.Composite (same as yours)
in database you can see its saving.


Thank you for your response. I've attempted to modify Linkmanagement.php with your code, but it still doesn't save neither.

just for testing purpose can you please add that code in core file to just confirm.
if it works will override it, later

added 2 rows in core file (vendor/magento/module-bundle/Model/LinkManagement.php) but it doesn't save neighter

in this function mapProductLinkToBundleSelectionModel

yes,I'm 100% sure.

it works fine for me
let me complete the whole module for you

i updated code with all the files

do let me know if that works, for time being i used static values but obviously we will use
    $selectionModel->setMinQty($linkedProduct->getMinQty());
    $selectionModel->setMaxQty($linkedProduct->getMaxQty());


Unfortunately it doesn't works,values are not saved in column.
Seems that there is a conflict with LinkManagement.php

I confirm my assumption, there is a module installed which override magento stock link management.
I've added the callout $selectionModel->setMaxQty(43);  in that file and it works!

@Petacchi That's great that it worked !! cheers
